# Programmatically defun a function with a given name

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to programmatically call a macro which is similar to `defun`, in order to define a function of a given (auto-generated) name. My attempt is this:

```
`(defun ,(intern "autogen-command-33") () (echo "autogen-command-33!"))
```

However, for some reason, `(intern ...)` stopped working as expected (it now complains like this):

```
invalid number of arguments: 1
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [TERMINATE-THREAD] Terminate this thread (#<THREAD "worker" RUNNING {10078C8DE3}>)

Backtrace:
  0: [error printing frame]
  1: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (INTERN "autogen-command-34") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  2: (EVAL (INTERN "autogen-command-34"))
```

So I replace `intern` with `make-symbol`, which gives no error. Then, I attempt `(autogen-command-35)`, expecting that it has been defined, but it hasn't:

```
STUMPWM> (eval `(defun ,(make-symbol "autogen-command-35") () (echo "autogen 35")))
#:|autogen-command-35|
STUMPWM> (autogen-command-35)
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION AUTOGEN-COMMAND-35 {10082F8D43}>.
STUMPWM>
```

How do I programmatically define a named function in common lisp?

Comment: `(eval `(defun ,(intern "autogen-command-33") () (echo "autogen-command-33!")))` works for me in SBCL. What is your `*package*`? can you try the same in `xterm` instead of `slime`?

Comment: apparently I had messed something and `intern` wasn't working correctly. It did eventually work as you and I would expect

Comment: General advice: it is often not a good idea to do something like this.  It can become unnecessarily hard to understand a program where you cannot find the place a specific function was defined.

Comment: in this case my goal was really to use the "defcommand" macro of stumpwm, to auto-define a number of simple commands  (eg make a certain keypress) that were specified declaratively in a config file, and I try to make it clear these are autogenerated (eg auto-... prefix and docstring) but I agree for normal functions it is best to avoid this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a symbol as the name of a function you want to call, there are a few things to consider:

- symbol names are uppercase internally, by default. So best create a symbol in the current case, typically uppercase.
- symbols of functions usually should be in a package. INTERN is the function for that. INTERN the symbol in the right package. Best to specify the package when calling INTERN. See the documentation of [INTERN](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/f_intern.htm).

Your symbol names were lowercase. MAKE-SYMBOL also just creates a symbol, but it is not interned in a package.

```
FOO> (INTERN "BAOBAB" "CL-USER")
COMMON-LISP-USER::BAOBAB
```

Comment: for some reason I get `invalid number of arguments` for `(INTERN "BAOBAB" "CL-USER")`

Comment: thanks. something was wrong with my `intern` function. the upper-case tip helped.